# Opencv ml header file not working

Tags: c++, opencv

https://github.com/vikram-ma/OCR
when I try to run main.cpp from this code i got the following error

```
In file included from /home/akash/Desktop/OCR-master/main.cpp:9:0:
/home/akash/Desktop/OCR-master/OCR.h:43:3: error: ‘CvKNearest’ does not name a type
   CvKNearest *knn;
   ^
CMakeFiles/OCR.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/OCR.dir/main.o' failed
```

please help

Comment: Which version opencv have you installed?

Comment: opencv version 3.2.0

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it seems you don't have OpenCV installed/downloaded.

The code you are poining to uses OpenCV library and it assumes you already have it.

You should go to [OpenCV releases](http://opencv.org/releases.html) and download the version you need.

**Edit:**

I looked into it more closely and as suspected the code was using an old OpencCV version. Right now you are using 3.2.0 so you need to make some updates to the code itself.

Either you should go with an older version of the library (which I'm not suggesting but will be probably less effort) like 2.3-2.4 or update the code to the version you've already installed.

If you wish to do the latter, you can start by looking here: [Transition guide](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/db/dfa/tutorial_transition_guide.html)

Among others, it is shown there that what used to be `CvKNearest` is now moved to `cv::ml::KNearest`. Updating accordingly should fix your first error.

Comment: It's quite difficult to guess further. Might be a different version of OpenCV issue. Might be that due to the ifdefs inside `OCR.h` the `ml.h` file is not included (this is where CvKNearest lays). But this is basically the thing - `CvKNearest` is not known since it has not been included at the point of `OCR` class file compilation.

Comment: did you run it in your machine?